# How to send an .apk file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to send an .apk file using JMeter but I'm getting a 'bad request' status code `400`

Yet in Postman it works.

**Postman:**

[image]

**JMeter:** 
[image]

and I'm getting below response:

```
{"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"This URI expects to receive multipart/form-data."}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in your configuration, i.e. in Postman I can see `file` as the Parameter Name and in JMeter there is `test`.

My expectation is that if you change `test` to `file` your request should start working normally.

See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/) article for more details on properly simulating file upload (and download) events using JMeter

---

Going forward be aware that given your request works in Postman you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-):

[image]

and when you execute the request in Postman it will be captured by JMeter.

Just remember to put the file you're uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm still not managing to solve it, also changing test to file gives the same result

Comment: If you need to upload a file to a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) endpoint and provide both [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and the file as the request [multipart payload](https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html) the request would be a little bit more complex, check [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/) article for example instructions